# Remove spacing between tab bar items (left and right)

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

How to remove spacing between tab bar items when using the "fill" value on the "item position" option?

I've tried the following:

```
    let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    tabBarController.tabBar.itemSpacing = 0
    let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBarController.tabBar.items!.count)
    let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBarController.tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBarController.tabBar.frame.height)
    tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor.secondaryHighlight(), size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)
    for item in tabBarController.tabBar.items! {
        item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

extension UIImage {

    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }

}
```

This result is always this (note the green line on the left of the first tab bar item):

[image: tab bar items]

Comment: Just a note @user3427013, I saw you remove the `!` from the edit, it is needed for the image to display (markdown syntax). I've added it back for you.

Comment: Thanks Yuchen Zhong

Comment: FYI, the typical use case for a tab bar is that the image & text itself change colors when the tab bar item is selected/deselected (for example, the circle and "First" text). You don't normally change the entire tab bar item background color.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AdamPro13 but the customer requested this UI... I have no other choice than to replicate the photoshop file.

Answer (score 4):

You can play with title offset that affects on image too:

```
    tabBar.items!.first?.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(30.0, 0.0);
    tabBar.items!.last?.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(-30.0, 0.0);
```

In this case result will be:
[image: result screenshot]

How it work with three items:
[image: three items result screenshot]

Comment: It doesn't work. :\ I still get the green line on the first and last tab bar items.

Comment: @user3427013 Maybe I missed something. I update my answer with photo for three items. Explain please result you try to get. (maybe with some screens)

Comment: It seem that problem is in size of your image. You set an image with size of barItem, but after changing offset - size of item will change, but image's size not.

Comment: I've added a static value for the size (width and height), but it still didn't work. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Try not to set image. Just use system one and see if result will be the same.

Comment: Even with 4 elements the spacing between the elements is still there. I initially thought dividing the tab bar's width by 3 would be the problem, but even dividing the width by an even number, the issue is still there.

Comment: but I need to set an image (CGRect) for the tab bar's selectionIndicatorImage, otherwise the background color (CGRect image) of the selected tab will not show.

Answer (score 1):

to be able to control the location of all tab bar items "not only the first and last" you can use the items array index like this:

`tabBar.items?[1].titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(-15.0 , 0.0) 
tabBar.items?[2].titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(15.0 , 0.0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2
    tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.width += 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. Hope this helps!

```
tabBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width + 4
tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2
```